# How to recursively identify cells of specific type in grid?

Tags: recursion, f#, tail-recursion

I'm learning F# and I'm building a minesweeper app. As part of that, I'm trying to have a method that detonates all adjacent mines if a mine is detonated, recursively.  So if I have a grid like:

```
     |  0  |  1  |  2  |
------------------------
  0  | E-1 |  M  | E-2 |
  1  | E-2 | E-4 |  M  |
  2  |  M  | E-3 |  M  |
```

and I detonate the mine in 0,1, it would in turn detonate the mine in 1,2 and that would in turn detonate the mine in 2,2. The mine in 2,0 would not detonate because it isn't adjacent to any of the others.

At this point I've actually implemented the field as a list:

```
module CellContents =
  type T = 
    | Empty of int
    | Mine
    | Crater

module Location =
  type T = { Row: int; Column: int }

module Cell =
  type T = 
    { Content : CellContents.T
      Location : Location.T }

module Field =
  type T = Cell.T list
```

What I'm having trouble with is how to start with cell 0,1 and the end up with a list of all mines that are adjacent. So, I need a list like (showing just coordinates):

```
let minesToDetonate = [ {Row=0;Column=1};{Row=1;Column=2};{Row=2;Column=2} ]
```

I have no trouble getting the adjacent mines for a specific location and then determining the mines from that group.

**What I'm having trouble with** is getting this to recurse somehow and go until there are no mines found adjacent, giving me a master list the mines I need to detonate.

Once I get the master list of mines, I can detonate them and build an updated field with those mines becoming craters.

**Update**
@Kevin's answer worked, but I had a hard time understanding it. In case others also have a hard time, I'm adding the function below, with comments and a couple of changes.

```
let detonateProximity (field:T) (start:Cell.T) =
    let rec inner cells m acc =
        match cells with
        | [] -> acc
        | x::xs -> 
            match x.Content with
            |Mine ->
              match proximity m.Location x.Location with
              // Continue but don't accumulate
              | Self -> inner xs m acc
              | Near -> 
                  // See if current cell has already been found
                  match acc |> List.tryFind (fun t -> t = x) with
                  // If it has, we're done. Pass out
                  // an empty list which ends recursion.
                  |Some _ -> [] 
                  // If it wasn't found (this parts hurts my brain)...
                  // calls function once for rest field and then
                  // using new starting point on whole field.
                  // Is this efficient at all?
                  |None -> List.concat [(inner xs m (x::acc));(inner field x (x::acc))]
              // Don't accumulate, continue with rest of mines.
              | Far -> inner xs m acc
            // Not a mine, keep going, don't accumulate
            |_ -> inner xs m acc

    // The set ensures no duplicates
    Set.ofList (inner field start [])
```

The `proximity` function (not shown) simply wraps up the logic that determines if the tested mine is the reference mine, close to it or far from it. E.g. `Self` is returned if the *distance* between the current cell and the mine is zero {Row=0, Column=0}.

Comment: Why you don't want to use a 2D Array instead of the Location and Cell?

Comment: Well, the initial reason was to work list manipulation hard, since I'm guessing in real life I'll use that more than arrays. I'm also wondering how *functional* a 2d Array solution would work. My understanding is that I'd either have to be re-allocating the field all the time, if I keep it immutable or I'd have to change the arrays state (i.e. change the values in the array).  I'd be open to thoughts on this and/or clarification. The main thing is that this project is to learn how to use F#, so I sometime make decisions based on what I'll learn rather than being efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return a set of all detonated cells including the one that started the chain reaction.

```
module Location =
  type T = {Row: int; Column: int }

  let subtract l1 l2 =
      {Row=l1.Row - l2.Row;Column=l1.Column-l2.Colum

let detonate (field:Field.T) (start:Cell.T) =
  let rec inner cells m acc =
    match cells with
    | [] -> acc
    | x::xs -> match x.Content with
               |Mine ->match subtract m.Location x.Location with
                       |{Row = 0;Column = 0} -> inner xs m acc
                       |loc when abs (loc.Row) < 2 && abs (loc.Column) < 2 -> 
                          match acc |> List.tryFind (fun t -> t = x) with
                          |Some _ -> [] 
                          |None -> List.concat [(inner xs m (x::acc));(inner field x (x::acc))]
                       | _ -> inner xs m acc
               |_ -> inner xs m acc
  Set.ofList (inner field start [])
```

If you just want a list of locations like in your question its easy to convert like so:

```
detonate board {Content=Mine;Location={Row=0;Column=1}}
  |> Set.map (fun t -> t.Location)
  |> Set.toList
```

Comment: thanks! However, as I'm still new to functional programming and my brain is about to explode trying to grok the logic =:-o. Any chance you could add some comments to explain what is happening? I'm really not understanding the ``tryFind`` match and why you are updating the accumulator when the match is ``None``.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so I don't know F#, so I'm going to write this in Python.

```
def getDetonationList ( startingWithThisCell ) :
    seen = set()
    current = set ( [startWithThisCell] )
    while current :
        # Get all the mine cells that are adjacent to every ones
        # we are currently exploring. Then remove the ones we're
        # currently exploring and the ones we've seen, just so
        # we don't duplicate effort later.
        nearby = allMinesAdjacentToCells(current) - seen - current

        # Mark that we've seen the current ones (add the current
        # ones to the overall seen ones
        seen.update ( current )

        # Now we start over, starting from the newly found mines
        current = nearby
        # Note that if this is empty, this list will end, which
        # means that we will have seen as many as we could have
        # seen.
    return seen
```

Comment: Ok, down-vote this all you want, but Python is also an excellent language for writing pseudo-code which shows you the path to HOW to do things even if it doesn't have copy-and-paste code for the taking.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Because I don't know F#, but a "how do I recursively find nearby cells" isn't a language question: it's a methodology question (unless you're using a stupid language).

Comment: @iAdjunct, while you are right that this is not necessarily a language question, it is a question related to the paradigm of how to do it functionally. You're example is not done functionally, but imperatively. I.e. you have a variable, ``seen``, that you are updating in a loop. In the functional paradigm, there would be no loop, because ideally I won't be updating a variable, but rather calculating a value. This is kind of the point of learning F# (or any functional programming language): to learn to think about problems differently.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know that F# was a function language. I suppose that explains the 'F'.